# Should we merge the [code-translation] and [source-to-source] tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I've found the tags [code-translation](/questions/tagged/code-translation) and [source-to-source](/questions/tagged/source-to-source), which appear to be about the same topic: automatic translation of one programming language to another programming language. Should these two tags be merged, or is there a distinction between these tags?